# Meteor Speech Recognition & Speech to Text on Mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, meteor, speech-recognition

My goal here is to use get some Speech to Text recognition with Meteor. I know that most device keyboards already have a Microphone button that enables Speech to Text, but I want to avoid having the users keyboard pop up.

To do this: I have been trying to use the webKitSpeechRecognition used [here](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html). I have it working on desktop just fine. But when I navigate to my localhost on my phone, or actually build the app on the mobile phone (Android Galaxy s5), weird things start to happen.

**When navigating to localhost:**
Rather than having the finalized text appear as it does on desktop, I get every iteration of what my recognition object thought. For example: if I said: '*Hello Stack*'.
I get: '*hellohellohello stackhello stack*'

**When launching Mobile App:**
The microphone never turns on. None of my console.logs come through and nothing ever happens.

[Here is a Gist of all my code](https://gist.github.com/ninth-mind/50ffcfc4d1ed18afe227). And here is the relevant parts. Everything else is pretty standard Meteor template.

```
    recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
    recognition.continuous = true;
    recognition.interimResults = true;
    Session.set('final_span','')
    Session.set('interim_span','')
    final_transcript='';


    recognition.onstart = function() {
      Session.set('listening',true)
      recognizing = true;
      console.log('started')
    }

    recognition.onresult = function(event) {
     var interim_transcript = '';
         for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
           if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
             final_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
           } else {
             interim_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
           }
         }
         Session.set('final_span',final_transcript)
         Session.set('interim_span',interim_transcript);
    }
```

I've looked for packages to solve this for me and didn't find any that worked.

TLDR: Any insight on how to get Speech Recognition on a mobile device using Meteor.

Comment: Have you figured out the answer?

Comment: @Ruby - Nope. moved on from this project.